# WPF Datepicker returns previously selected Date using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker

I am working on a WPF project where I have a Datepicker control on a Window. I am using MVVM pattern for data bindings. I have setup a command on SelectedDate changed event of the Datepicker. The problem is that for e.g., when first time I change the date I get **NULL** in the event handler of the command. And when I changed the date again, then I get the previously selected date in the event handler. This is a strange behaviour as this doesn't happens if I don't use WPF commands and work in code behind model.

***Here is my xaml code snippet for DatePicker:***

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpEventDate" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="150,0,150,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedDateFormat="Long" 
            SelectedDate="{Binding Path=., Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today},  StringFormat=Today is {0:dddd, MMMM dd}}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedDateChangedCommand}"
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dpEventDate, Path=SelectedDate}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <DatePicker.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightYellow"></SolidColorBrush>
    </DatePicker.Background>
</DatePicker>
```

***Command event handler in ViewModel class***

```
get
{
    return new DelegateCommand((sdate) =>
    {
        selectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(sdate);
        if (sdate != null)
        {
            //some logic here
        }
    }  
}
set
{
    SelectedDateChangedCommand = value;
    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedDateChangedCommand");
}
```

**DelegateCommand class implements ICommand**

So in above code "**sdate**" parameter always return a previously selected date. And if it is the first time I change the date it returns **NULL**.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by binding the change to the event and command. Is there a reason why you don't bind the `SelectedDate` Property of your DatePicker (using `TwoWay` mode)? Currently you're binding it to a static `DateTime.Today`.

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpEventDate" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="150,0,150,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedDateFormat="Long" 
      SelectedDate="{Binding MyDateTimeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and in your ViewModel having a

```
private Nullable<DateTime> myDateTimeProperty = null;
public Nullable<DateTime> MyDateTimeProperty {
    get {
        if(myDateTimeProperty == null) {
            myDateTimeProperty = DateTime.Today;
        }
        return myDateTimeProperty;
    }
    set {
        myDateTimeProperty = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MyDateTimeProperty");
    }
}
```

This way your ViewModel will return the current date and set it in the DatePicker, if the date is null previously and if the DatePicker is changed, it will bind it's new way back to the property.

Comment: Thanks for your time Tseng. Actually the reason I am binding DatePicker's SelectedChange Event to the command is:

1. I want to respond to the changed event in the viewmodel.
2. Based on that changed date, I would be querying a wcf service to query the data again.

Thanks

Comment: Well you can still do that. You bind the SelectedDate like above to the `ViewModel` and in the trigger you call the command (parameterless) and it gets it's value form the ViewModel property. Can't test it now, so not 100% certain if the property is set before the Trigger and got go go now. You could give it a try though