# Datepicker passing parameter through command parameter wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a WPF MVVM project using `Prism`, I have a `Datepicker` that is binded to a `Datetime` property on the viewmodel. I would like to use the `SelectedDateChanged` event to get the changed value (no code behind). I understand I get the value change in the property that `Datepicker` is bound too, but I would like to try it another way. So far I have put together the datepicker in xaml as so

```
<DatePicker Name="dpName" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" SelectedDate="{Binding Class.Date}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ath=TestMeCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </DatePicker>
```

C# code for the `TestMeCommand`:

```
public DelegateCommand TestMeCommand { get; set; }
```

in ctor:

```
TestDateCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(TestPateparam);
```

The function:

```
 private void TestDate()
    {
        int test = 0;
    }
```

My question is how do I pass the selected date to a function as a parameter. So far I have tried replacing the `InvokeCommandAction` to

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TestDateCommand}" CommandParameter="Binding ElementName=DPLoanDetailsAsOfDate, Path=SelectedDate}"  />
```

and the c# function

```
  public DelegateCommand<object> TestDateCommand { get; set; }
  TestDateCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(TestPateparam);

      private void TestPateparam(object dt)
    {
        int test = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your command parameter binding lacks a leading {.  Not sure if that's the problem.  And if you're using commands to perform validation, you're doing it wrong.  Use INotifyDataErrorInfo to do your validation.

Comment: Does Debugger come to `TestPateparam()`? if do, just see what `dt` has.

Comment: You cannot do using InvokeCommandAction. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659070/wpf-datepicker-returns-previously-selected-date-using-mvvm

Comment: setup, Ayyappan Subramanian the debugger does go to TestDateParam but I dont get the date as the paraeter I get "Binding ElementName=datePickerName, Path=SelectedDate}", I set the parameter in this case as an object not a DateTime

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Prism 6.1.1-pre2 you can easily do this with Prism's InvokeCommandAction:

```
    <DatePicker  Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged">
                <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" TriggerParameterPath="AddedItems" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DatePicker>
```